# collection_selec Rails no toma clase de CSS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

estoy renderizando un JS en rails pero el `colletion_select` no me toma una clase de css que estoy colocando.

name file: **options.js.erb**

```
var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:item_pro, :name, @items, :id, :name, {class: 'style-colletion'}))%>";
$('#act').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres añadir una clase a un elemento, puede usarlo de está forma:

```
$('#act').addClass("style-colletion");
```